# Flake 8: "multiple statements on one line (colon)" only for variable name starting with "if"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, mypy, flake8

I'm using `flake8` in Visual Studio Code, writing some code using [Python 3.6 variable annotations](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#variable-annotation-in-python-3-6-with-pep-526). It worked without any problems so far, but I encountered a strange warning.

This works fine:

```
style: str = """
width: 100%;
...
"""
# Doing sth with `style`
```

This too:

```
img_style: str = """
width: 100%;
...
"""
# Doing sth with `img_style`
```

This however does not, it yields below warning:

```
iframe_style: str = """
width: 100%;
...
"""
# Doing sth with `iframe_style`
```

[image: flake8 warning]

Well, technically it does work fine; the code runs. But somehow `flake8` is not happy with this.
The multiline string and the code following is always the same.

**When I omit the "f" (`i_rame_style`), I don't get a warning, too! So I guess for some reason flake8 thinks of a `if foo: bar()` here!?**

What am I missing here? Is this a bug in `flake8`?

Comment: What if it's just a Visual Studio problem ? Since your code compile and runs as you said it, i don't see any reason why it would be flake's fault.

Comment: Seems to me that something, most probably VSC, is trying to be smart with a post-process split of common mistakes before sending it to flake.

Comment: I'm using just the `ms-python.python` extension, and I believe that's where flake8 support is built in. It uses the flake8 command line tool installed via pip after all.

Comment: i just tried it with plain flake8 and the error is the same... this might get interesting.

Comment: @etene thanks! That would have been my next shot... As I said, I have no clue what's going wrong, but to me it seems like this is an issue with flake8, which produces these messages.

Comment: Yeah, `flake8` is wrong here.  You can [look up the warning](https://lintlyci.github.io/Flake8Rules/rules/E701.html), and it's explicitly to stop people from writing `if` statements like `if x: do(y)` all on one line.  It might be worth submitting an issue on their [gitlab page](https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/issues)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit: The problem is in pycodestyle (pep8), which is called by flake8. The rest still stands.**

**Second edit: I've made some more research and the issue is fixed [here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/pull/640). The fix hasn't been released yet, though.**

Definitely looks like a flake8 bug to me:

`flakebug.py`:

```
innocuous: str = ""
ifstarting_string: str = ""
forfalse_positivetoo: str = ""
whilethis_lookslikeabug: str = ""
elsehaha: str = ""
```

In the shell:

```
$ # python3.6 -m pycodestyle flakebug.py gives the same results
$ python3.6 -m flake8 flakebug.py 
flakebug.py:2:18: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)
flakebug.py:3:21: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)
flakebug.py:4:24: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)
flakebug.py:5:9: E701 multiple statements on one line (colon)
```

Looks like every line starting with a control flow statement triggers it.
I'd wager it uses a regex like `(if|else|while|for).*:`.

I'll try to get to the bottom of this and update this answer if I can, meanwhile you could add some `# noqa` annotations and you'll be set :)

Comment: Thank you for testing! I almost forgot about `# noqa`, always trying to make flake super happy :D
If this turns out to be a flake bug I'll open a bug report for sure later this day, In case nobody else did until then. You are most likely right with that regex thing...

Comment: Actually the bug is in pycodestyle (a.k.a. pep8), which flake8 uses. Watch out for this if you submit a bug ! I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: And you're welcome ! I use flake8 daily so this is _really_ relevant to my interests.

Comment: Good catch, finding that link from your second edit! It was merged in June 2017 tho, they could probably hurry up a little. Until then, I'm able to silence the warning. Thanks again, question answered!